# Gridstack.js Drag'n'Drop performance issues

Tags: javascript, gridstack

I'm trying to fix Drag'n'Drop performance of [gridstack.js](https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js) when using Internet Explorer 11. On our site one experiences about 400ms delay during the mousemove event: (theres many more inline css analyses below the end of the screenshot)

[image]

On the Gitgub repo (gridstack.js is being no longer developed) there is already an [issue](https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js/issues/845) open by user mvkampen, but I don't get the explanation:

> For now I made a quick and dirty fix which improves performance. By
>   collecting all rules in an array and reduce them at the end to a
>   single textNode. Which is appended to the sheet.ownerNode ()

I get the array part but how am I supposed to reduce this array into a single textNode? I tried using `setAttribute()` on all these array elements into an DOM Object but no selector matched, as the grid element hasn't been created at this point yet. So how am I supposed to do this, if I have to avoid [this](https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js/blob/develop/src/gridstack.js#L1109) costly code block, that seems to be the issue for the performance impact?